# Multiple target frameworks causes CS1503

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, overloading

Whenevre I try to build with this csproj I get multiple CS1503

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;net471</TargetFrameworks>
    <RootNamespace>Dtl</RootNamespace>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

for example

```
string[] lines = pair.Key.Split(Environment.NewLine);
```

yields:

> CS1503   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'

I tried net461 with no luck either. if I revert back to just netcoreapp2.0 it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.NET framework` API doesn't have a `String.Split` method that takes a string as the only argument.  The `.NET Core` API does have such a method.  If you want to support `.NET framework` then you can only use methods that exist in that API.

```
pair.Key.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Reference:

[.NET Core String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-2.0#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_)

[.NET Framework String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_)